# not able to add decimals in the loop after reading it from the file

Tags: cobol

I am not able to add two decimal numbers after reading it from a file, inside the file the number's are defined as 1234.10 and so on, I am looping in the program to add these numbers, but getting SOC7 while using a third variable to add the details from the file, i have defined all the numeric variables as 9(4)v99 and tried using s9(4)v99 comp-3, but still not adding.

the program works only if the decimals inside the file is defines as 123410 instead of 1234.10 inside the file.

this is how i coded,

```
READ-PARA1.                                               
READ FILEX                                            
  AT END                                              
     MOVE 'Y' TO WS-EOF-IND.                          
READ FILEY                                            
  AT END                                              
     MOVE 'Y' TO WS-EOF-IND.                          
DISPLAY SPACE                                         
DISPLAY OCODE1,'    'ACODE1,'    'POLNO1,' 'EDATE1,   
          ' 'PHOLD1,' 'LOCATION1,' ',LICNO1,' 'VMAKE1,
' 'VMODEL,' 'YEAR,' 'PREM'  '.                        
ADD 1 TO R1.                                          
MOVE PREM TO PRESUM1.                                 
ADD PRESUM1 TO PRESUM.
```

in working storage section including file descriptor above it,

```
  05 PREM PIC S9(4)V99 COMP-3.                
  05 FILLER PIC X(34).                        
  WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.                        
  77  R1 PIC 9(2) VALUE 0.                        
  77  PRESUM PIC S9(4)V99 COMP-3 VALUE 0.         
  77  PRESUM1 PIC S9(4)V99 COMP-3 VALUE 0.        
  77  PRESUM2 PIC S9(4)V99 COMP-3 VALUE 0.
```

Answer (score 1):

The V in pic 9(4)V99 is an assumed decimal; there is no decimal point. It will only accept numbers like 123410. It will not accept 1234.10

For 1234.10 you would need to define it as

```
   03 f1      pic 9(4)
   03 filler  pic x.
   03 f2      pic v99.
```

and in the program

```
   compute PRESUM = f1 + f2.
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by Bruce Martin will work but you could also try defining the "number" as `PIC X` something in
the input file and then use `NUMVAL` to convert it to a numeric value. Something like:

```
01  FILEX-REC.
    02 ....
    02 PREM    PIC X(7).
    02 ...

01.
    02 PRESUM1     PIC S9(4)V99 PACKED-DECIMAL.

    COMPUTE PRESUM1 = FUNCTION NUMVAL(PREM) END-COMPUTE
```

The `NUMVAL` function takes a character string (PIC X) and converts it into a numeric data item. This will convert the character representation of the number in `PREM` into a packed decimal (COMP-3) in `PRESUM1`.

By the way... every new COBOL programmer runs into this little problem and it usually takes them a while to sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

Numbers like 1234.56 should be defined as:-

```
     05  PREM                   PIC 9999.99.
```

You need to tell the compiler to expect a number in character format with an actual decimal point embedded.

Comment: Numeric Edited fields (as you suggest using above) cannot be used for arithmetic operations. For example `ADD 1 TO PREM` will generate a compile error.

Comment: @NealB -- True,  but you can MOVE them to a real numeric field.

Answer (score 0):

A S0C7 is a data exception error.  If the data in a packed field isn't in packed format, or if data in a zoned field isn't in zoned format, this error will occur.  Thankfully, S0C7s aren't very pernicious (like S0C1s and S0C4s, which are rare in COBOL, thank God) so it's not too tough to suss them out.

I am assuming you are reading the values of PRESUM and PRESUM1 from a file?  What is in the file?

The funny thing is that often a COMP-3 or zoned field will not complain about invalid data until you try to use it, such as adding to it or adding it to something else.

Without knowing what bytes (not the value, but the BYTES) that make up the COMP-3 packed fields, there's no way to diagnose this S0C7.

If you or anyone else needs more information on zoned or packed data, I can provide tons... I've been programming in COBOL for far more years than I care to admit.